# Relation to property names and data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In many uses of data one thing confuses me. EG in CoreData and the NSManagedObject subclass's property names are the same as the properties in the CoreData attributes. Similar things go on with the NSXMLParser.

Why is this? it's confusing to me because I never see the string for the name of attribute being used. While NSLoging a fetch request object I get,

```
    "<Person: 0x6d5be20> (entity: Person; id: 0x6d5dce0 <x-coredata://6800B6A5-87AF-46B4-9836-9D412A9B3EE4/Person/p1> ; data: {\n    age = 51;\n    firstName = Anthony;\n    lastName = Robbins;\n})",
```

As one of the array elements. I wouldn't expect any different.

But in the tutorial when I itterate through the array using

```
    for (Person *thisPerson in persons)
```

(thisPerson being the data object with the mysterious properties). The property names seem to have been sorted according to name.

```
            NSLog(@"First Name = %@", thisPerson.firstName);
```

Why the hell is this? Surely a barrage of NSRegex expressions and string modifications would be required to extrapolate this data.

Comment: Your question is not very clear -- particularly mixing a question about Core Data with a question about NSXMLParser. What exactly are you asking? What makes you think the property names have been sorted? If you define attributes, why don't you expect the NSManagedObject to have properties with the same name?

Comment: My question is why property names have to be the same as the data type they extrapolate. It seems to me that a property simply called 'dataNode' can get data out of an array by virtue of it being formatted as, 'dataNode = "data"' in the array. 

It's really confusing as I see this behavior cross completely different things like CoreData and NSXMLParser. And it's a big uncertainty that I need to be able to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Core Data (**not** NSXMLParser) Core Data simply uses the property name to look up the corresponding property in the model. If you're accessing `lastName` on an `NSManagedObject` instance with `foo.lastName` there should be no implementation for

```
-(NSString *)lastName
```

This will cause the NSObject class to fall back to `NSKeyValueCoding` which will turn that call into

```
[foo valueForKey:@"lastName"]
```

The `NSManagedObject` class overrides `-valueForKey:` (and other `NSKeyValueCoding` relating methods) and uses that to access data through the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Comment: Ahh. But doesn't something similar happen with NSXMLParser.

Comment: Please mark an answered, if this answers your question. Ask a separate question for NSXMLParser -- it's something completely different than Core Data.

Comment: No it's not, the question I am asking is about the relation to property names and elementNames is it the same?